# Using Subqueries to get a percentage from a number of SQL columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an oracle database ischema with a 'Goals' table, the table has 5 columns:

```
G_ID - Int  
M_ID - Int  
G_Method - Text  
G_X_Loc - Int   
G_Y_Lo - Int  
G_Time - Int
```

The G_X_Loc and G_Y_Loc are integers between -5 and +5. I need to work out, as a percentage, how many goals were scored between Y0 to Y+5 and how many were scored between Y0 and Y-5.

So far I've managed to use the following query to tell me the numbers for 0 to +5, which is 56, but I'm struggling to work it as a percentage of the total rows (107).

```
Select COUNT(G_ID) AS Y_POS_GOALS  
FROM GOALS  
WHERE G_Y_LOC IN (Select G_Y_LOC  
FROM GOALS  
WHERE G_Y_LOC BETWEEN 0 AND 5)
```

Could anyone give me a steer on a better way to go about this?

Comment: Counting to five (or six?) skills not present?

Comment: Oracle Apex is just a tool, an interface. Your database is not in apex, apex is in the database. This question is just good old sql, ran on the oracle database, and has nothing to do with the use of apex. Maybe if you had eg issues with an interactive report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT AVG( CASE WHEN g_y_log >= 0 THEN 100 ELSE 0 END ) AS g_y_positive_percentage,
       AVG( CASE WHEN g_y_log <= 0 THEN 100 ELSE 0 END ) AS g_y_negative_percentage
FROM   goals;
```

Comment: Very nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Oracle Apex, but below query is standard SQL and runs in Oracle and most other RDBMS:

```
select 
  count(*) as total,
  count(case when g_y_loc between 0 and 5 then 1 end) as cnt_pos,
  count(case when g_y_loc between -5 and 0 then 1 end) as cnt_neg,
  count(case when g_y_loc between 0 and 5 then 1 end) / count(*) * 100 as prz_pos,
  count(case when g_y_loc between -5 and 0 then 1 end) / count(*) * 100 as prz_neg
from goals;
```

Comment: Thorsten, thank you very much- that seems to have done the trick!